# mismatched multipleSelect with jQuery Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am using multipleSelect addon from this webpage : http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

It works good, but if I add jquery Forms class (form-control) to the element, the element is mismatched:

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT7e4.png)

Code:

```
<select class="form-control multiSelect" style="width: 200px;" multiple> <option selected>Test</option> <option>Test2</option>  </select>

$('.multiSelect').multipleSelect();
```

Is there a possibility to change it ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Edit the CSS yourself?

Comment: put your code here.

Comment: done, but the code is very easy, I am using standard settings